# int returned from android jni is the wrong value

Tags: java-native-interface, int, return

I have an int in android java which value is about 100
I print it to the Log to make sure.

When I return it from a static method to C++ it has a value of 1585156834

Here is the C++ code

```
jint GameLayer::QueryBonesCollected()
{
jint jreturner;
jint returner;
JniMethodInfo methodInfo;
if (! JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, CLASS_NAME, "QueryCollectedBones", "          ()I")){
return 0;
}
methodInfo.env->CallStaticIntMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID,jreturner);
methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);
returner=jreturner;
return returner;    }
```

and the java method:

```
public static int QueryCollectedBones()
{Log.v("keith", "BonesCollected=" + BonesCollected);
int returner=BonesCollected;
return returner;}
```

and the java field:
    public static int BonesCollected;

Comment: You don't need to call `DeleteLocalRef()` there. It happens automatically when you return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
jreturner = env->CallStaticIntMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID);
```